# Authenticity guarantee(d)

Tags: past-tense

I was wondering if you could help me out with the phrase "Authenticity guarantee". Is it proper English to use this?

Would  "Authentic guarantee" or "Authenticity guarantee**d**" be more correct?

Comment: The **authenticity** is **guaranteed** by an **authentic guarantee**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either one can be used in certain circumstances.

"Authentic guarantee" is a *noun phrase*; it means a guarantee that is genuine or legitimate, as opposed to a fake guarantee. This is fairly unusual, since a guarantee is usually either trustworthy or not based on whose name is on it, and it's rare for someone to stamp a guarantee on in someone else's name. "Authentic**ity** guarantee" is a slightly different noun phrase that means a promise or guarantee that something will be authentic. So a product might have an authenticity guarantee that gives conditions for some compensation if the product isn't authentic. This is much more plausible.

"Authentic**ity** guarantee**d**" is a *noun* followed by a *verb*; it means that something *has had a promise made* that it will be authentic, and implies that the promise still holds. (It looks like past simple tense at first glance, but I suspect there's actually an ellipsis to leave out "has been", making it really present perfect. Alternatively, it's a *noun* followed by a verb's *past participle*, leaving out the connective "is", with the same meaning.)

So if you're referring to the promise itself, you'd use the first one; if you're just saying that a promise *exists*, you'd use the last. Because "authenticity guaranteed" is a more-or-less complete, if terse, sentence, it's considerably more common in advertising of various sorts.

(Similarly, you can say "I guarantee authenticity", which means that you promise it's authentic.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and clear answer Nathan! Have a great day ahead :)

Comment: PS: When you promote a product or service that a user hasn't experienced yet, the common use seems to be 'Guaranteed to love'. Following your explanation, would 'Guarantee to love' be more correct in this case? Thanks!

Comment: @TimVanGorp: You might want to ask that as a new question, actually; it's got some quirks to it. But in particular, there's definitely ellipsis going on there.

Comment: Done :) http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/77875/guaranteed-guarantee-to-love

Answer (score 3):

"Authentic guarantee" means the guarantee is authentic (as in the guarantee is real) whereas "authenticity guaranteed" is commonly used as a mark to promise the genuineness/realness of a product.

In a sentence, I would say "the authenticity of X is guaranteed" to promise the genuineness of X.

Comment: Typically, "authenticity guaranteed" is used in advertisements on TV or in print. I imagine a bright red spiky circle with "Authenticity guaranteed!" written in it. They try to minimize texts in advertisements.

Comment: @AlexK However, the formal statement of exactly what the guarantee guarantees might well be headed *Authenticity Guarantee*. :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, it all makes sense now. :) Have a great day ahead!