# Guaranteed / Guarantee to love

Tags: tense, present-perfect, present-tense

When you promote a product or service that a user hasn't experienced yet, would you use 'Guarantee to love' or 'Guarantee**d** to love'?

Comment: Even though you are asking about a tagline, try writing these phrases in a full sentence, and see which one makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question revolves around the use of **guarantee**.

> You are **guaranteed to love** our new thingamajig with our money back **guarantee**

Is a tag line that might be used be used to extoll consumer to buy your product.
**Guaranteed** in this context has the meaning **to be assured**.
It is a **verb**.

> Wedding vows are a **guarantee to love** one another.

Here, **guarantee** has the meaning of an **oath** or a **contract**.
It is a **noun**.

Comment: Thanks for your time and clear answer Peter. Have a great day ahead. :)